# Too broad tags like science and pseudo-science

Tags: discussion, tags

I just removed the [science](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/science) and [pseudo-science](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pseudo-science) tags from one question. Those tags apply to nearly all questions and are therefore pretty much useless.

I think we should remove them from any question if they appear again. Can we get a consensus here about those tags and other similar ones that appear?

It is much easier to clean up the tags early than to do it retroactively.

**Edit:**
I have also removed [quackery](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quackery) and [evidence](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/evidence). Quackery already contains a judgement on the validity of the claims and it is extremely broad, I don't think that makes a useful tag. Evidence is also a [meta-tag](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/) and not useful.

Comment: I agree. They also make good candidates for blacklisting. They basically cover all questions on topic and give little to no information on the question.

Comment: As one who used the tag removed in first place I agree.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, certainly. Remove these types of tags.

There are two types of tags which are *explicitly* discouraged: meta-tags and redundant tags.

**Meta-tags** are a problem because they do not tell you what the question is about. They describe something like:

- The author's motivation for asking the question (stupid, funny, quackery, etc)
- What *kind* of question is being asked (subjective, poll, request, etc)

Each tag should be able to stand on its own to tell you what the question is about. For example: the tag "subjective", taken alone, doesn't tell you *anything* about what the question is about. If it cannot pass that acid test, remove it.

**Redundant** tags are those that are already *implied* by the site topic. There's simply no value to tags like [skeptic], [science], [pseudo-science], [woo], [debunk], [proof], [argue], [question], [discussion], … You can see where I'm going.

We accumulated these types of tags for years before we figured out how harmful were in organizing the site. There’s no reason to repeat those mistakes. Each community can benefit from those mistakes and do it better the next time around. This is one of those cases.

See: [**The Death of Meta Tags**](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/)

Answer (score 0):

Pseudoscience isn't a useless tag, as not all crackpot ideas are pseudoscience. Pseudohistory, conspiracy theories and the like are [on-topic](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60/is-skeptics-only-for-pseudoscience-or-for-pseudohistory-and-the-like).