# Is Skeptics only for pseudoscience, or for pseudohistory and the like?

Tags: discussion, scope

Most of the questions here are about pseudoscience, such as homeopathy and anti-vaccination. Are other forms of fringe theories, such as Gavin Menzies' *1421* on-topic?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think so. In my opinion, all crackpot theories are on-topic. I'm sure at least *some* people would like to refute all the 911 truthers' theory and that falls under the pseudohistory umbrella.

Comment: I agree, those questions can be answered objectively, and they would fit pretty well onto this site.

Comment: I agree too - pseudo-history, conspiracy theories and such are quite central to skepticism.