# Should the question asking instructions be referring to "scientific skepticism"?

Tags: discussion, site-faq

The "How to Ask" has "Is your question about scientific skepticism?" (as does the default for the question title), and the FAQ has "Skeptics - Stack Exchange is for skeptics, rationalists, free thinkers, or anyone who questions pseudoscience.".

However, the only answer to [Is Skeptics only for pseudoscience, or for pseudohistory and the like?](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60/is-skeptics-only-for-pseudoscience-or-for-pseudohistory-and-the-like) argues that all crackpot theories, including pseudohistory, are on-topic for the site.

Should the "How to Ask" and the FAQ be edited?

Comment: Interesting point.

Answer (score 1):

You're misreading it.

It's meant as "the *scientific process of skepticism*" not "*skepticism about science*".

See the /faq which has clarifying text.

Comment: The FAQ only refers to the field of science, not other fields of knowledge (such as history).

Comment: @andrew history questions can be answerd through *the scientific process of skepticism*. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_method "To be termed scientific, a method of inquiry must be based on gathering observable, empirical and measurable evidence subject to specific principles of reasoning"

Comment: I'm pretty sure the FAQ is at least partially referring to the field of science, not just the methodology of science, because it refers to physics and nutrition (sub-fields of science) and "research-level science", and it mentions pseudoscience.

Answer (score 0):

I think we should change "scientific skepticism" to just "skepticism".

"scientific skepticism" as Jeff explains it is not a standard phrase and I think most people will read it to mean only questions in the domain of science are welcome.

It is implied in the ideology of a skeptic that the scientific method is followed, and this is further clarified in the FAQ.

Stating in a few places that questions should relate to "scientific skepticism" is poorly worded and potentially going to turn away new users.

I think there is nothing to be gained from keeping it as "scientific skepticism" but potentially something to be lost.

Comment: I think you make a good point that the term scientific skepticism may not be well understood. I think the goal is to distinguish what we do from other forms of [skepticism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skepticism), such as academic skepticism or Cartesian skepticism. How would you suggest we do that?

Comment: @Oddthinking I feel that the skepticism we do is somewhat obvious, just as it is with many skeptics clubs or organizations around the world. For people not familiar with what a skeptic in this sense is, the FAQ imo does a good job of clarifying.